# Skroller creating large empty space on mobile phones

Tags: skrollr

I am using the skroller on a page. The page on mobile devices is showing a large space which is not scrollable after first time you scroll it. Visited so many websites offering solution, including StackOverflow and @Prinzhorn's own comments on the same, but some how I am unable to fix the problem on mobile devices (Android, iPhone).
Here is HTML:

```
<div id="skrollr-body">
<div id="eidwish1" class="centered" data-300="width:100%; background-image:linear-gradient(0deg, hsl(0, 100%, 50%), hsl(40, 50%, 50%));" data-2000="width:0%; background-image:linear-gradient(3600deg, hsl(360, 100%, 50%), hsl(400, 100%, 50%));"><h1 class="text-center heading2 wow fadeInDown" data-0="display:block;" data-1500="display:none;">This Eid send your loved ones...</h1></div>
<div id="eidwish2" class="centered" data-2000="width:100%;" data-2500="width:0%;"><h1 class="text-center heading2 wow fadeInUp" data-0="background-image:linear-gradient(0deg, hsl(0, 100%, 50%), hsl(40, 50%, 50%));" data-2500="background-image:linear-gradient(3600deg, hsl(360, 100%, 50%), hsl(400, 100%, 50%));">a personalized Greeting Card!</h1>
<div id="crescent" class="centered" data-1500="top:-100px;" data-2000="top:-200px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="ribbon-left" class="ribbon" data-2500="width:0%;" data-3500="width:50%;"></div>
<div id="ribbon-right" class="ribbon" data-2500="width:0%;" data-3500="width:50%;"></div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="337px" height="200px">
</svg>
<div id="pattern1" class="centered" data-2500=" height:100%; "data-3500="height:0%;"></div>
<div id="pattern2" class="centered"></div>
<div id="eidwish3" class="centered" data-4000="width:0px;height:0px; "data-5000="width:700px;height:700px;"></div>
<h1 class="text-center headerUp wow lightSpeedIn" data-0="display:none;" data-4000="display:block;"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/><span clss="toggle-green">THINK GREEN </span><span class="toggle-blue">PRINT GREEN</span></br><small><i>use "EID-2015" promo code when you checkout</i></small></h1>
<h1 class="text-center discount wow rollIn" data-0="display:none;" data-4000="display:block;">We are Giving Away 25% discount</h1>
<a class="button btn-success buy-now text-center wow jello" data-wow-iteration="10" data-wow-duration="3000ms" data-0="display:none;" data-4000="display:block;" href="Greeting Cards">See All Card Designs</a>
<a class="copyright" href="http://example.com">
<img src="http://example.com/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
<br>Copyright © example.com 2015-16</a>
</div>
```

This is JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = skrollr.init({
forceHeight: false
});
```

and CSS:

```
html, body {padding:0;margin:0;
k}
body {overflow:auto; height:7600px; 
}
#skrollr-body {min-height: 1px; float: left; width:100%; height:100%; 
}
#skrollrk-body  div {overflow:hidden; position:absolute; 
}
.centered { top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; 
}
#eidwish1 {background: #000 center center no-repeat ; z-index:5;
}
#eidwish2 {background: #000 url('wish2.png') center bottom no-repeat ; z-index:4; box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px #FF0000;  background-size: cover;
}
#crescent {width:100%; background:url('crescent2.png') no-repeat; margin-top:0px;
}
#pattern1 { background:url('wish3.jpg') ; z-index:2; background-attachment:fixed; background-size: cover;
}
.ribbon {background:#FF0000; height:40px; top:50%; margin-top:-20px; z-index:3;}
#ribbon-left {left:0
}
#ribbon-right {right:0
}
small { color: #fff;
}
svg {position:absolute; z-index:5; left:50%;  top:50%; margin-left:-170px; margin-top:-180px
}
#pattern2 { background:url('wish4.jpg'); z-index:1; background-size: cover
}
#eidwish3 {background:#FF0000 url('wish5.jpg') no-repeat center center; z-index:10; border-radius:50%;  background-size: cover
}
```

I am stuck on this for many days. I have read almost every thread about this and tried to do the same, but it doesn't solve my problem. Pleas help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm exactly with you on this topic.  Oh how I wish I could talk to somebody about skrollr.  Here's a few things I've learned about Skrollr and Mobile:

- You need to really understand the differences between mobile browser and desktop.
- Of special note is Mobile Layout Viewport vs Visual Viewport. I'd start here  http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html, and here http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

> However, the CSS layout, especially percentual widths, are calculated
>   relative to the layout viewport, which is considerably wider than the
>   visual viewport.Thus the  element takes the width of the layout
>   viewport initially, and your CSS is interpreted as if the screen were
>   significantly wider than the phone screen. This makes sure that your
>   site’s layout behaves as it does on a desktop browser.
>
> How wide is the layout viewport? That differs per browser. Safari
>   iPhone uses 980px, Opera 850px, Android WebKit 800px, and IE 974px.

- This is a pretty big deal.  If for you both desktop and mobile Layout / Visual Viewports are same size, then you can make your website essentially functional in mobile using the touch system.  It will look and function pretty much just like desktop scrolling.
- If those viewports are hugely different widths, its a no go.  I had a website controlled fully by heights, so I was out of luck.  I ended up adding a few 'static' screens to the bottom of my page.  I added two classes (.my_website_mobile and .my_website_desktop) I would `display: block;` or `display: none;` as appropriate. I wasn't happy doing that but it worked.
- In mobile, a div with a background-image can not have `background-position: fixed`  That will work great on a desktop browser mobile emulator tool but will fail terribly on a real mobile device.  (hard lesson learned...)
- Other functions likely to have odd performance on mobile: overflow, and visual viewport  I used a lot of `vw` (Viewport Width) and `vh` (Viewport Height) heights instead of % for locations and sizes.  Those make sense on desktop, not so on mobile.
- Reminder,  `skrollr-body` gets `style="-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px); transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);"` upon skrollr initialization.
- If you are on a mobile device, then: `<html  class="skrollr skrollr-mobile" style="overflow: hidden;" >` and `<body style="overflow: hidden;">` after skrollr initialization.
- If you are on a desktop device, then:  `<html class="skrollr skrollr-desktop">` and `<body style="height: 12345px;">` after skrollr initialization.

I haven't dug into your specific code, but if you want to talk more, contact me via email (check my profile...)  I'm totally up for it.  I need to change machines and my location before I am able to troubleshoot your code...